# Is there mistake in passing parameters to push_relabel_max_flow()?

Tags: c++, boost

So this is my code to get max flow though network using push_relabel_max_flow function in Boost C++ lib.

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/graph/push_relabel_max_flow.hpp>
typedef boost::adjacency_list_traits<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS> Traits;

struct VertexProps {
    std::string name;
};

struct EdgeProps {
    long capacity;
    long residual_capacity;
    Traits::edge_descriptor reverse;
};

typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, EdgeProps > DirectedGraph;

int main() {
    DirectedGraph g;
    Traits::vertex_descriptor s, t;

    s = boost::add_vertex(g);
    t = boost::add_vertex(g);
    boost::add_vertex(g);

boost::add_edge(s, 2, { 33, 0 }, g);
boost::add_edge(2, t, { 33, 0 }, g);
auto capacity = boost::get(&EdgeProps::capacity, g);
    auto reverse = boost::get(&EdgeProps::reverse, g);
    auto residcap = boost::get(&EdgeProps::residual_capacity, g);
    auto indexmap = boost::get(boost::vertex_index, g);
    std::vector<DirectedGraph::vertex_descriptor> vertices;
int flow = boost::push_relabel_max_flow(g, s, t,capacity,residcap ,reverse,indexmap);
    std::cout << flow;
    return 0;
}
```

after running this code, it gives as error

```
Exception thrown at 0x008D2551 in ConsoleApplication4.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004.
```

Is there something I am missing? What is the problem here?

Comment: you're obviously dereferencing a null-pointer. Use the debugger.

Comment: @TheTechel so,what should i do?

Comment: [`There are several special requirements on the input graph and property map parameters for this algorithm. First, the directed graph G=(V,E) that represents the network must be augmented to include the reverse edge for every edge in E. That is, the input graph should be Gin = (V,{E U ET}). The ReverseEdgeMap argument rev must map each edge in the original graph to its reverse edge, that is (u,v) -> (v,u) for all (u,v) in E. The CapacityEdgeMap argument cap must map each edge in E to a positive number, and each edge in ET to 0.`](http://www.boost.org/libs/graph/doc/push_relabel_max_flow.html)